# stream video from struts2 action multiple contentType?

Tags: java, struts2, mime-types

I am trying to play video file, for my action contentType is set to

> application/octet-stream

now if i change it to audio/mpeg, then user cant download other types of files. I would like to simply know can we set multiple content type if so how? and if its not possible what should i do in a situation where user can upload and download anytype of file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can.

You must output the **[Stream Result type](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/stream-result.html)** from your Action, and specify a *parametric contentType*, for example:

Struts.xml

```xml
<result name="success" type="stream">
  <param name="contentType">${yourContentType}</param>
  <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
  <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${yourFileName}"</param>
  <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
</result>
```

Action

```
@Getter @Setter private InputStream inputStream;
@Getter private String yourContentType;
@Getter private String yourFileName;

public String execute() throws Exception {

   yourContentType = "audio/mpeg";
   yourFileName = "yourStuff.mp3";
   byte[] yourContent = loadTheContentInSomeWay();

   setInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(yourContent));        

   return SUCCESS;
}
```

You can parameterize the `contentDisposition` part to specify when a file must be opened as `attachment` (ask for download) or `inline` (open in browser) according to your needs.

Comment: byte[] yourContent = loadTheContentInSomeWay(); i didn't understand

Comment: <source src="Sample.mp4" type="video/mp4"/> this is working when i put video (Sample.mp4) under web content in eclipse but not system location

Comment: @srinivasgowda You need a way to load your byte[] from the source you have: from a File, from a database, from a Service, from a Queue, ecc.... Since it is not relevant to this answer, I've wrapped it in a fake method called `loadTheContentInSomeWay();`. Pretty much self-explanatory, I hope(d) :)

Comment: can you see this question tell where i need to correct          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44126896/how-do-i-play-multiple-videos-in-jsp-using-struts2