# display image from Mysql database without storing to local system

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, struts2, blob

I'm developing a Struts application where I want to display images present in MySQL DB in BLOB datatype.

I don't want to store those images to local system but I want to directly display them in a browser. We need to store them in an temp memory.
I am able to fetch it and store it into `FileOutputStrem` and from this object i need to pass an image to JSP.

Below is the code

```
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

if (result.next()) {
    Blob blob = result.getBlob("photo");
    InputStream inputStream = blob.getBinaryStream();
    // read the input stream...

}
```

Please let me know how can I do this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i just need to display image present in mysql DB without saving it to local machine as i c there are n number of resources which shows me to write it into local machine

Comment: Use `stream` result.

Comment: Storing them in memory would probably lead to memory leaks and 切腹.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16300376/1654265

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
byte[] content = result.getBytes("photo");
response.setContentType("image/jpg");
response.setContentLength(content.length);
response.getOutputStream().write(content);
```

Html Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "servleturl",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#content").html('<img src="'+result+'" >'); 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "servleturl",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#content").html('<img src="'+result+'" >'); 
            }
        });
    });
});

Comment: i want to fetch images from database and add to bean to get into jsp

Comment: Can you please try  private byte[] data; in your bean and set data = result.getBytes("photo"); And add <img src="${bean_name.data}" alt="car_image"/> in jsp