# How do i play multiple videos in jsp using struts2

Tags: jsp, video, struts2

Hi everyone i was tried to play video in jsp page which get success. How do i play multiple videos in jsp, the video files are in specific folder(File system)
below is the code to display one video file

**Jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <video width="400" controls>
 <source src="<s:url value="videoStream" />" type="video/mp4"/>
  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
</body>
</html>

**struts.xml**

<struts>
    <package name="user" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="videoStream" class="com.pradeep.videostream.VideoStreamingAction">
            <result name="success" type="stream">
                <param name="contentType">${yourContentType}</param>
                <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
                <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${yourFileName}"</param>
                <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
            </result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**action class**

```
public class VideoStreamingAction extends ActionSupport {
    private InputStream inputStream;
     private String yourContentType;

        // getters and setters 

 public String execute() throws Exception {
           yourContentType = "video/mp4";
           File file =new File("D://svn videos//Create Java Spring Web MVC Project With Maven [EDITED].mp4");
           setInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file)));   
           return SUCCESS;
        }
}
```

**i changed my my jsp like this**

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="getFiles">
<input type="submit" value="check">
</form>
<s:iterator value="filesList">
     <video width="400" controls>    
      <source src="<s:url value='getFiles.action?fileName='/><s:property/>" type="video/mp4" />     
      <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg"> Your browser does not support HTML5 video. </video> 
</s:iterator>
</body>
</html>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<struts>
    <package name="user" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

    <action name="getFiles" class="com.pradeep.videostream.VideoStreamingAction">   
    <result name="success">index.jsp</result>   
    </action>

        <!-- <action name="videoStream" class="com.pradeep.videostream.VideoStreamingAction">
            <result name="success" type="stream">
                <param name="contentType">${yourContentType}</param>
                <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
                <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${yourFileName}"</param>
                <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
            </result>
        </action> -->
    </package>
</struts>
```

**action class**

```
public class VideoStreamingAction extends ActionSupport {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private InputStream inputStream;
    private String yourContentType;
    private File[] filesArray = null;
    private List<String> filesList = new ArrayList<String>();

//getters and setters

    public String execute() throws Exception {


        File folder = new File("D://svn videos");
        filesArray = folder.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < filesArray.length; i++) {
            String fileName=filesArray[i].getName();
            filesList.add(fileName);
        }

        HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
        HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        String fileName = request.getParameter("fileName");
        System.out.println("GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG "+fileName);

         File file = new File(fileName); 
        setInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file)));
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play multiple videos, you need multiple streams.

Since the Stream result of an action represents *one* stream, you need multiple actions.

For example, you can make many AJAX calls to different actions, or to the same action passing the name of the file you want to play as parameter... but I don't get why on earth you should want to play multiple videos at once. We have two eyes and a brain, and really su*k at multitasking so... the question is not clear.

Comment: i too know i have two eyes and a brain, the thing is i dont want to play all videos at a time i just want to display multiple videos at a time in jsp so that user can select any one from multiple video from jsp

Comment: Well, there are many ways to do that, it is really too broad. Should they start caching ? Would you show a thumbnail or the actual video, when they're stopped ? It's a quite big topic with a lot of personal opinions on how to do that. You can still use AJAX by the way, you can't do it with a single action.

Comment: i am new to ajax, can you share the idea that how can i do this

Comment: <body>
<ul>

</ul></body>

Comment: $.ajax({
 type : 'POST',
 url : 'getFiles',
 dataType : 'JSON', 
    success : function(data,success) { 
 $.each(data,function(index , values) { 
     var newRow="<li><video width='400' controls><source src="+data[index]+" type='video/mp4'/>";
     $("#vid").append(newRow);
  });        
},
});